# Angular Variable/Function Global Scope

Tags: angularjs, scope, global-variables

I have a variable that i use almost everywhere in my app, in many different controllers.
I'm looking for the best possible way of setting that variable knowing that :

-The variable will need to get updated from a controller and resulting in an update on the whole app ( other controllers mainly).

-Some of those function are instance of an object with function in itself that have a callback , does that cause any issue?

So far there seems to be 2 way of doing that :
rootScope but that rarely advised apparently:

```
myApp.run(function ($rootScope) {
   $rootScope.var = "string";
});
```

And building a custom directive ( but what about setting it's variable ?)

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('test', function() {
 return {
     test : 'string'
  };
});
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction and help me choose betweem the two?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a `service` or `factory`  save that value in someService.variable and the broadcast n event that this value has been changed. I am attaching sample code. It may contain some syntactical error but I want to give you an idea

```
  angular.module("myapp")
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, myService) {
    $scope.change = function() {
      myService.var = 'abc';
      $rootScope.broadcast('varChanged');
    };
  })

.controller('myOtherCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, myService) {

    $rootScope.on('varChanged', function(e) {
      use(myService.var);
    });
  })
  .service('mySerice', function() {
    this.var = '';

  });
```